# Getting return data from message to Android handler

Tags: android, handler

Today I am sending some data to a handler for a non-static call to OpenFeint methods. Everything is fine up to the point of return, where I don't know how to retrieve the information.

Method call in main class:

```
public static float getPercentageAchievement(String idAchievement) {
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.what = OpenFeintXHandler.GET_PERCENTAGE_ACHIEVEMENT;
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(BUNDLE_ARG_1, idAchievement);
    msg.setData(args);
    ms_kOpenFeintHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    return msg.getData().getFloat(BUNDLE_RETURN); // msg is empty here
}
```

Message handling in handler class:

```
case GET_PERCENTAGE_ACHIEVEMENT:
        msg.getData().putFloat(
                OpenFeintX.BUNDLE_RETURN,
                otherGetPercentageAchievement(msg.getData().getString(
                        OpenFeintX.BUNDLE_ARG_1)));
        break;
```

Test method in handler class:

```
private float otherGetPercentageAchievement(String idAchievement) {     
    return 200;
}
```

Comment: did you fix this issue if yes can to let me how you did it . thanks

Comment: I stopped using handlers altogether.

Comment: what method did you use then

Answer (score 6):

You can set data in this format

While setting data

```
Message msg = new Message();
msg.obj = data which you want to set // for object data
Msg.arg1  = data which you want to set // for integer data
```

While getting data

```
String data = (String) msg.obj; // If object is of String
int integerData = msg.arg1;
```

`msg.arg1` will pass only one data at a time you can also pass data in `msg.arg2` they both are of integer types

Comment: Did you read the code? I am already doing that and is not working. Arg1 and arg2 are only valid for int paramethers.

Comment: msg.getData().putFloat(
                OpenFeintX.BUNDLE_RETURN,
                otherGetPercentageAchievement(msg.getData().getString(
                        OpenFeintX.BUNDLE_ARG_1)));
Whats that u r doing

Comment: My idea is to store the return in the message bundle to retrieve it from the other method, but it appears the message is cleared when it is sent to the handler.

Comment: just divide your process of calling method otherGetPercentageAchievement() and storing back the data in the msg

Answer (score 1):

But why do you insist in receiving the return value in the message?
Think that the message is sent asynchronously so the return statement can be executed before the value is setted in the handler...

I would do:

```
String data=otherGetPercentageAchievement(msg.getData().getString(OpenFeintX.BUNDLE_ARG_1));
//use the data directly in the handler...set a variable in other class or whatever you want to do here.
```

Comment: Edited for clarification. It was other method in handler class with the same name.